# WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service over net tcp

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf, tcp

In my project I have one WCF Service which is hosted in a Windows Service. I hosted the WCF Service in Windows Service over `netTCPBinding` and Installed Windows Service. To access WCF service in my silverlight project I have added service reference of wcf.
But, when I am calling a method in WCF Service am getting the following error :

> Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFHost/.
>   The connection attempt lasted for a time
>   span of 00:00:03.2951885.
>   TCP error code 10013: An attempt was made to
>   access a socket in a way forbidden by
>   its access permissions..
>   This could be
>   due to attempting to  access a service
>   in a cross-domain way while the
>   service is not configured for
>   cross-domain access. You may need to
>   contact the owner of the service to
>   expose a sockets cross-domain policy
>   over HTTP and host the service in the
>   allowed sockets port range 4502-4534.

Please help me out.

Comment: Are your service and web site hosted on the same machine?

Comment: no my wcf service is hosted in windows service

Comment: I see, and I take it then that the service is on another machine. Are the two machines on different domains (most likely with a firewall separating them)? If so, you need to open up a port on the firewall to allow the service call to go through.

Comment: windows service is on my local system and am running my silverlight application from visual studio

Answer (score 0):

For same-machine connections rather make use of Named Pipe bindings.

It might help if you showed us your service and client side endpoint configurations.

**EDIT**: After reading up a bit on the error you're getting ([here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/f5e7fdb3-3736-416d-94f0-e625709ce914/) among other sites), try changing the port number from 8732 to something between 4502-4534 as the error message suggests.

Comment: my wcf service app.config file is as follows

Comment: Lol, not seeing it... maybe show us your Silverlight app.config as well. If you say it works using a console app, then it the problem most likely lies with the Silverlight client.

Comment: my wcf service app.config file end point are as follows :                                                  <endpoint name="NetTCPEndPoint" address="" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="WCF.IWCFHost">
</endpoint>
<endpoint name="NetTCPMetaDataPoint" address="mex" binding="mexTcpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

Comment: <configuration> <system.servicemodel> <bindings>      
<customBinding>
<binding name="netTCPBinding_TestClient">          
<binaryMessageEncoding/>
<tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647" />
</binding>
</customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
<endpoint address="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFHost/"
binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="netTCPBinding_TestClient"
contract="TestClient.IWCFHost" name="netTCPBinding_TestClient" />
</client> </system.serviceModel> </configuration>

Comment: I could be missing something, but where's the address for your service?

Comment: actually i posted only endpoints in my wcf and here is my wcf service address : <host>
          <baseAddresses>            
            <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:8732/WCFHost/" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>

Comment: @ahobul: Sorry for only getting back to this now, was out for a while. Maybe I'm being a bit pedantic, but try dropping the last '/' character from the address, i.e. `net.tcp//localhost:8732/WCFHost`. Also, when using TCP it's often useful to enable port-sharing on your PC, then you don't need to specify a port for your TCP address. Although I would do it differently in this scenario: try using named pipe bindings; if both the service and the client resides on the same machine, you don't need to use TCP.

Comment: @ahobul: Also, I notice in your client endpoint you specify that the binding is a `customBinding`, while on the service it's a `netTcpBinding`. Try changing the binding of the client endpoint to `netTcpBinding` as well. Also, under `<bindings>` in your client app.config, change the `<customBinding>` tag to `<netTcpBinding>`.

Comment: Thanks tobias for your suggestions in solving my probnlem its just setting <security mode="None"/> in app.config file of WCF Service Library.Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Keep same protocols at both the server and client end. May be your are calling the service with different protocols. Also check if your are using nettcp, your are having access to the machine where service is hosted.

Answer (score -4):

use basicHttpBinding instead of netTCPBinding