# WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service + Silverlight + Silverlight Application

Tags: wcf

In my project am using WCF Service hosted in Windows Service.
Am able to get service reference of my wcf service to my Silverlight Application, But when i call a method in wcf service am getting error as follows :

Protocol exception was Unhandled by User-Code :

The server at net.tcp://localhost:4502/WCFHost/ rejected the session-establishment request.

Please help me out

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Service Hosted in Windows Service over net tcp](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727599/wcf-service-hosted-in-windows-service-over-net-tcp)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely a missing/incorrect client access policy. [This article walks you through setting it up](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx). Just ignore the IIS related stuff and make sure you have the policy correct.

Comment: thanks for response.What am doing in my project is am accessing wcf service hosted in windows service from silverlight application.Is this possible over nettcp protocol.                                                     Please help me out. Thank you.

Comment: thanks for all of your great responses i solved my problem. Thanks alot.

Comment: so did I answer your question?